# Why group by aggregate didn't return group by columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have empty dataframe with `columns: [order_id, uid, payment_channel, user_paid_amount, vertical]`

when I use `df.groupby(['uid','vertical']).payment_channel.agg('count').reset_index()` 
its returns empty dataframe with `Columns: [uid, vertical, total_transaction]`

But when I use `df.groupby(['uid','vertical']).user_paid_amount.agg('sum').reset_index()`
its returns empty dataframe with `Columns: [index, gmv]`

How to use aggregate summation function but still maintain the `uid` and `vertical` column

**EDIT**
sample dataframe

```
IN [] :  empty_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['uid','vertical','topup_payable_amount'])
         empty_df.dtypes
OUT[] :  uid                     object
         vertical                object
         topup_payable_amount    object
         dtype: object
```

Comment: can you post reproducible sample dataframe?

Comment: @MohitSharma already added dataframe, you can use above data and group by code in the question

Answer (score 1):

On an **empty** Dataframe, created the way you did, results of both
your instructions are:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [uid, vertical, payment_channel]
Index: []
```

and

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [index, user_paid_amount]
Index: []
```

Note that as far as the **aggregated column** is concened, I got the
**original** column name.

You can "rename" this column, passing *name* parameter to *reset_index*, e.g.
`df.groupby(['uid','vertical']).user_paid_amount.agg('sum').reset_index(name='xyz')`
(or whatever other name).

I use *Pandas* version *0.25.3* and *Python* version *3.8.0*.
If you have some older version, upgrade and repeat the test.

And now let's get down to the names of grouping columns in the result.

Note that if you created an **empty** DataFrame, then *Pandas* has no
information on column types.
Normally (if some data rows had been provided), the type of each column
would have been inferred from the source data, but not in your case.

This is why the type of all columns (including *user_paid_amount*) is set as **object**.

The consequence is that you can not *sum* on such a column (you can only
on **numeric** columns).
Apparently, instead of rising an exception, the *Pandas* code takes some "exceptional"
path of execution, giving the above weird result (grouping column named as *index*).

## How to put things right

After you defined the DataFrame, change the column type, at least for *user_paid_amount*:

```
empty_df.user_paid_amount = empty_df.user_paid_amount.astype(float)
```

Then execution of:

```
print(empty_df.groupby(['uid','vertical']).user_paid_amount.agg('sum').reset_index())
```

gives the "normal" result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [uid, vertical, user_paid_amount]
Index: []
```

And the final remark: Don't use such name as *empty_df*.
This Dataframe is empty for the time being, just after creation,
but at some point later it will contain some data (and will not be empty).